# Where is System.SpanExtensions?

Tags: c#

Net core 2.0
I'm trying to find NonPortableCast() the api browser shows it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.spanextensions?view=netcore-2.0):

I've referenced System.Memory - but I cannot find this method. Its pretty new so I'm not seeing much in the way of online discussion around it either. Additionally all articles I've found that talk about it, dont seem to mention where it is located.

I've referenced System.Memory and opened the assembly in JustDecompile and I dont see SpanExtentions in there anywhere.

Comment: You didn't mention what framework you are targeting.  Are you targeting .Net Core 2.0?

Comment: Oops, yes core 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the inclusion of this in the documentation for the 2.0 release was a mistake:

https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/30156